# Center align Shiny box header with HTML or CSS

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
    filetime <- format(file.mtime("mydata.csv"), format = "%a %e-%b-%Y %r IST")

    ui <- dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "Recruitment"),
      dashboardSidebar(),
      dashboardBody(
        shinyUI(fluidPage(
         box(verbatimTextOutput("final_text"), status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE, width = 12, title = "Collapsable text")
    ))))

    server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
      output$final_text <- renderText({
        HTML(paste("<center>","Last updated at", filetime, "</center>")) #"<font size=\"2\">",
      })
    }
```

In the above code the `Last updated at and filetime` are not getting center aligned, upon further research I found that `center` tag does not work on HTML5, not sure if that's causing the problem.

As a workaround, I added a `div and class` to center align the text via css, here is my 2nd attempt.

```
#Next to fluidPage
tags$style(HTML(".man_made_class{color:#f2f205; text-align: center;}")),
#Then further in Output
  output$final_text <- renderText({
    HTML(paste("<div class= man_made_class>","Last updated at", filetime, "</div>")) #"<font size=\"2\">",
  })
```

In both my attepmt, I am able to change `color`, `font size`, `margin` etc, but not able to center align the text. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to add custom class, as the textOutput already has a unique id `final_text`. Working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
filetime <- format(file.mtime("mydata.csv"), format = "%a %e-%b-%Y %r IST")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Recruitment"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
      tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                                #final_text {
                                  text-align: center;
                                }
                                div.box-header {
                                  text-align: center;
                                }
                                "))),
      box(verbatimTextOutput("final_text"), status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE, width = 12, title = "Collapsable text")
    ))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$final_text <- renderText({
    HTML(paste("Last updated at", filetime))
  })
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The final_text gets center align, I need the header of the box to be center aligned. Thanks

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Yup, the box header is center align, but all boxes on the chart gets center align. I only want the #final_text box to be center aligned

Answer (score 0):

Do this to changes to ui.R and server.R help?

ui.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
    #filetime <- format(file.mtime("mydata.csv"), format = "%a %e-%b-%Y %r IST")

    ui <- dashboardPage(
            dashboardHeader(title = "Recruitment"),
            dashboardSidebar(),
            dashboardBody(
                    shinyUI(fluidPage(
                            tags$style(HTML(".man_made_class{color:#f2f205; text-align: center;}")),
                            box(htmlOutput("final_text"), status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE, width = 12, title = "Collapsable text")
                    ))))
```

server.R

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
            output$final_text <- renderText({
                    "<div class= man_made_class>Last updated at xxxx</div>"
            })
    })
```

Comment: This does create the class however, the box title is is not yet center align